# Склоняется ли аббревиатура БИК?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, аббревиатура, склоняемость

Пишу текст для банка, у него везде написано "Укажите 9 цифр БИКа".
Мне кажется, надо "Укажите 9 цифр БИК". Как правильно и почему?

Answer (score 2):

Вот что о таких аббревиатурах говорится в [справочнике Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=94#pp94):

> § 205. Звуковые инициальные аббревиатуры пишутся прописными буквами, напр.: *ООН, МИД, НОТ, ОМОН, ГАИ, СПИД, ГЭС, ГРЭС*. По традиции пишутся строчными буквами некоторые (немногие) звуковые аббревиатуры: *вуз, втуз, дот, дзот*. Отдельные звуковые аббревиатуры могут писаться и прописными, и строчными буквами, напр.: *НЭП* и *нэп*, *ЗАГС* и *загс*.
> При склонении звуковых аббревиатур окончания пишутся только строчными буквами (без отделения окончания от аббревиатуры дефисом или апострофом), напр.: *рабочие ЗИЛа, работать в МИДе, пьеса поставлена МХАТом.*

БИК является звуковой аббревиатурой, читается единым словом (то есть подпадает под указанное правило), поэтому *может* склоняться.

Инициальные аббревиатуры склоняются, если читаются по слогам и род ведущего слова совпадает с родовой формой самой аббревиатуры (в нашем случае — мужской род).
Это тоже аргумент в пользу склонения.

Следует отметить, что если уж вы начали склонять аббревиатуру, то делать это надо на протяжении всего текста. Вот ошибка из Википедии ([БИК](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)):
*Классификатор **БИКов** ведёт Центробанк РФ...

Структура **БИК** и порядок ведения справочника определены в Положении...*

В учебнике Т. Бондаревой "Организация бухгалтерского учета в кредитных организациях"  аббревиатура склоняется:
*В расчете ключа участвуют все цифры номера счета, при этом ключ изначально имеет значение «0» и последние три цифры из номера корреспондентского счета банка (или [БИКа](https://books.google.ee/books?id=FgBrDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%20%D0%91%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=P8rEkXuUAu&sig=ACfU3U0zwndRinaM_tgn-JAJkVqLo1FnEA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDp-vs5Kf1AhWkxIsKHe1-CgIQ6AF6BAgjEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%20%D0%91%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%B0&f=false)).*

[Дополнительная информация о сокращениях](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Не добавляются** окончания к аббревиатурам, которые читаются по буквам *(СССР, США, ФРГ)*.

Но **добавляются** окончания к аббревиатурам, читаемым как целое слово *(ТАССа, МИДом, сотрудники ЗАГСа, соответствует ГОСТу)*.

"БИК" читается как слово, а не по буквам (Бэ-И-Ка). Посему эта аббревиатура **склоняется**.